# Sum of measurable and non-measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

The context of my question is probabilistic. The Doob-Dynkin lemma asserts that a r.v $X$ is $\sigma (Y)$ measurable iff it's a deterministic function of $Y$. Now, the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E} (X\mid Y)$ may be viewed as the best approximation of $X$ using deterministic functions of $Y$. I want to know whether $X-\mathbb{E} (X\mid Y)$ is necessarily *not* a function of $Y$, in other words, not $\sigma (Y)$ measurable.

More generally, is the sum of a measurable function with a non-measurable function generally non-measurable?

Comment: It shouldn't be, in general. Assume $\sigma(X)$ is any non-trivial $\sigma$-field, and let $\sigma(Y)$ be the trivial $\sigma$-field so that $Y$ is constant. Then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, then $X-\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable if and only if $X$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable.

More generally, if $(S,\mathcal A)$ is a measure space and $f,g\colon S\to\mathbb R$ are maps, $f$ is Borel-measurable but not $g$, then $f+g$ is not Borel-measurable. Otherwise, $f+g-f$ would be Borel-measurable as a sum of two such functions.

Comment: Even more generally, if $G$ is a group, $H \subset G$ is a subgroup, $x \in H$ and $y \in G \setminus H$, then $xy \in G \setminus H$.  Apply this with $G$ being the group of all functions under addition, and $H$ the subgroup consisting of measurable functions.

Comment: Wow, I was thinking about projections.. Now I realize my question is embarrassing! Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 4):

I think it is always a non measurable function.

let $f$ be the measurable function and let g be non measurable then if $f+g$ is measurable say $h$. Then $h-f=g$ is measurable, a contradiction.